# Bind the model when remote action method returns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

This is my property

```
[Remote("IsUserAlreadyExist","Admin",AdditionalFields="User_Id,NT_Login_Name",ErrorMessage=Constants.ErrorMessage.UserAlreadyExists)]
public string NT_Login_Name { get; set; }
```

And the action method looks like :-

```
public JsonResult IsUserAlreadyExist(UserModel umodel)
{
  CommonAdapter commonAdapter = new CommonAdapter();
  Dictionary<string, object> spParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();            
  spParameters.Add("inNTLogin", umodel.NT_Login_Name);
  DataSet userdetails = commonAdapter.ExecuteSP(Constants.SPName.GetUserByNTLogin, spParameters);
  if (userdetails != null)
  {
    if (userdetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
      if (umodel.User_Id > 0)
      {
        umodel.IsUserExists = true;
      }
      else
      {
        umodel.IsUserExists = false;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      IsUserOnLDAP(umodel);
      umodel.IsUserExists = true;
    }
  }
  return Json(umodel,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The model returning correct values but its not binding in the textbox on my view like this

```
<td class="tds">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NT_Login_Name, new { @id = "txtNT",     @class = "txtbox" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NT_Login_Name, "", new { @class = "errormessage", @validationgroup = "btnSubmit" })
</td>
```

Comment: Return `true` or `false`, not the model. `return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: How you are loading/assigning the view once after the `IsUserAlreadyExist` call? Could you show the script as well if you use...

Comment: @RJK, Its `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of Remote attribute is do some action and return either boolean or string in json format

But in your case you are returning a model

```
return Json(umodel,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I guess you have to modify your code to return

```
return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

if the the validation succeeds and

```
return Json("Some String", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

if the validation fails.

Something like this

```
public JsonResult IsUserAlreadyExist(UserModel umodel)
{
  CommonAdapter commonAdapter = new CommonAdapter();
  Dictionary<string, object> spParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();            
  spParameters.Add("inNTLogin", umodel.NT_Login_Name);
  DataSet userdetails = commonAdapter.ExecuteSP(Constants.SPName.GetUserByNTLogin, spParameters);
  if (userdetails != null)
  {
    if (userdetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
      if (umodel.User_Id > 0)
      {
        //umodel.IsUserExists = true;
        return Json(false,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }
      else
      {
        //umodel.IsUserExists = false;
        return Json(true,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      //IsUserOnLDAP(umodel);
      //umodel.IsUserExists = true;
      return Json(!IsUserOnLDAP(umodel),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
  }
  return Json(false,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: No need to return a message (its already been specified in the attribute) and no point setting the value of `umodel.IsUserExists` - its not being saved anywhere so its lost as soon and the method returns (the property seems to be somewhat pointless anyway)

Comment: I got your point. But at least you have to 

return Json(false,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

for the default message to be displayed.

Comment: I know - that why I stated in my comment 3 hours ago :)

Comment: Yes, there is no point setting the value of umodel.IsUserExists. I just reused the code from the question and added return statements

Comment: And, 

return Json("Any Message",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
return Json(false,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

are same. Because what ever is not true is false

Comment: Yes I know, but by returning the message here, your overriding the message OP has already set in the attribute, so unless there is a specific reason to display a different error message its not necessary. I'm making the suggestions so you will edit the answer and will be more likely to get upvoted :)

Comment: OK. I got it. I am editing it now. Thank you for the suggestions